# Excel export functionality - from jQuery dialog window

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, download

I need to create the functionality for Excel export from jQuery dialog window. I have anchor link and click the link it goes to Struts action class to pull the data from DB and export.

**I'm calling the method using jQuery like:**

```js
jQuery.ajax({
     url : '<s:url action="partexport"/>',
     data : "filters.productNbr" : $("#productsTextArea1").val()
});
```

**Struts action class :**

```
public String method {
    -----------------
    method to call backend...
    --------------------------
    httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    String filename = filters.getPeriod() + "_" +filters.getRegion() ;
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-disposition",
    "attachment; filename="+filename+".xls");
    ServletOutputStream outputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.flush();
    return NONE; 
}
```

It returns `null` , but suppose to download `xls` sheet. Is there any possibilities here to implement Excel export function  ?

Comment: Your ajax url looks rather odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the binary stream to the output from the action:

```
String filename = filters.getPeriod() + "_" +filters.getRegion() ;
httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+filename+".xls");
ServletOutputStream outputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
Path fileIn = Paths.get(filename);
Files.copy(fileIn, outputStream); 
outputStream.flush();
return NONE;
```